# rollsum only if non zero using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to calculate rolling sum, but I need the rolling sum of non zero values only.

I have below code which I am using for rolling sum:

```
a = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
pd.Series(a).rolling(3).sum()
Out[67]: 
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     1.0
3     2.0
4     2.0
5     2.0
6     2.0
7     2.0
8     2.0
9     2.0
10    3.0
11    2.0
dtype: float64
```

But I need result as below:

```
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     1.0
3     2.0
4     0.0
5     2.0
6     2.0
7     0.0
8     2.0
9     2.0
10    3.0
11    0.0
dtype: float64
```

If there is 0 in original series it need to be kept as 0 in the rolling sum output. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `.where` call after the rolling sum.

```
a = pd.Series([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0])

a = a.rolling(3).sum().where(a>0, 0)
```

Output

```
0     0.0
1     0.0
2     1.0
3     2.0
4     0.0
5     2.0
6     2.0
7     0.0
8     2.0
9     2.0
10    3.0
11    0.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean:

```
s = pd.Series(a)
s.rolling(3).sum() * s
```

Output:

```
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     1.0
3     2.0
4     0.0
5     2.0
6     2.0
7     0.0
8     2.0
9     2.0
10    3.0
11    0.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: maybe `*s.astype(bool)` incase there's a 2 in there somewhere :D

Comment: Nice one , good idea with the multiplication..retains `NaN` too